# How to logout by erasing all variable stored?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a logout function,

```
   $scope.logout=function(){
    $state.go('app.login');
    }
```

But my requirement is simply not go to login page, I want to go to login page by removing all variable i stored using service and as cookies, I don't want any instance of past user, what should i do?
I want to be like a refresh, but don't use refresh.

Comment: what type of authentication are you using? How is it set up?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information to be answered. Please add detail code....

Comment: as per your query with out updation Answer is already there in question "Erase" but HOW ? you need to update your code or plugins you are using to store cookies or you can find the documentation for clearing cookies or clearing local storage or deleting windows.localstorage  when function called ..  commonly you need to find a command to clear & execute it in logout function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to set `cache:false` in the `.state` routing as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using a service to handle your authentication. For instance, create a service called `AuthenticationService` and you could create the following methods on it.

```
.service("AuthenticationService", ["$state", function ($state) {
    this.clearSession = function(){
        // write your code to clear variables you mentioned in your question
    }

    this.doLogout = function($state){
        this.clearSession();
        $state.go('app.login');
    }

    return {
        clearSession: this.clearSession,
        doLogout: this.doLogout
    }
});
```

Then when you need to logout in your app, just call `AuthenticationService.doLogout`.

Edit: Not sure why this was downvoted, have provided the user with a solution based on his poor question quality.